# Firefox 102.0.1 will NOT open system dialog when clicking the browse/upload button

Tags: firefox, 22.04, dialog

I'm having a problem with my Firefox 102.0.1 in a relatively fresh Ubuntu 22.04 installation. I cannot get ANY system dialog to open when I try to save a page going to `File | Save` and/or `<CTRL+S>`. To make it even worst for my need, I still cannot get the system dialog from coming up when I click on a button to browse for a file I want to upload to the page. No bueno!

I tried running the code from w3schools [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_file.asp), both from the "Try it yourself" feature and locally from an HTML file with the code below, but nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
          <title>Dialog Test</title>
     </head>
     <body>
          <h3>My Firefox will NOT show the system dialog when I will the button below:</h3>
          <form action="/action_page.php">
            <label for="myfile">Click Me!:</label>
            <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile"><br><br>
          </form>
     </body>
</html>
```

I'm very frustrated!  I don't know where else to look!  I have searched Google and here off course.  I'm probably missing something extremely simple, I Just can't figure it out.

Your help will be extremely appreciated it.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried refreshing Firefox? Uninstalling and reinstalling?

Comment: I did a 'sudo apt install --reinstall Firefox' but no remove /reinstall.  I did install Chrome on the side after this message, and Chrome has no problemo.

Comment: Replacing the snap version of firefox with apt might help. https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/124466

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much.  That now makes me wonder why that happened, it is such an off issue.  I guess I'll be digging in.  Again, thank your for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by removing the snap version of Firefox and installing the traditional deb package.  I followed the steps here https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/124466 as suggested by Archisman Panigrahi in his comment above.  Thank you Archisman!